# Recalculate checksum in SVN dump after manual changes

Tags: svn, svndump

As we are migrating with a project to a public source hosting, I wanted to remove some “personal” information from the SVN repository. I did fine so far with removing paths or revisions using [`svndumptool`](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool) and `svndumpfilter`. However I want to remove some text from a particular file in the repository as well.

I removed the text manually by regex’ing the dump and that worked fine, but when I want to use the dump, I get a checksum mismatch. This is obviously because I changed the file but didn't update the checksum.

Is there any tool that recalculates the checksum for the files in a dump? Or is there a *good* editing tool for files (should allow regex replacements) inside a svn dump that also updates the checksum?

Comment: Easy path: remove the file entirely, reinsert as fresh copy.

Comment: You mean adding it as a new revision to the end? I want to keep the history intact though.

Comment: You could also simply run `sed '/Text-content-md5/d' dumpfile.txt | svnadmin load repo` to remove the checksum check for desired revisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I didn't want to wait longer for answers, so I wrote a script myself, which I will share with you. It utilizes [SvnDumpTool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/), or rather its library. To do custom actions you are required to edit the source (and know a bit python). A simple example is included and I think the abstraction the script provides is quite good.

Anyway, hope it is as useful for you as it was for me, although it took me quite a while to get it working like that:

**[SvnDumpToolEdit.py](http://gist.github.com/616231)** on Github.